# How to resolve separate packages in eclipse 2020?

Tags: eclipse, package

I'm using the eclipse *version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)*. When I create a package within a package, it is separated as in the image below:

[image]

I want the **me.isaac.com.events** child package to stay inside the **me.isaac.com** parent package as in the model below:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a setting you can change.

Go to the three dots on the top right of the package view and select hirachical packages.

The default setting shows flat packages, meaning that every package is displayed one after another.

Comment: Oh my god, that's what I needed, thank you very much!

Comment: I was frustrated about this too.